# Parallel For loop in C# with shared variable

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, .net-4.5

I'm trying to use parallel processing to speed up a couple of nested loops, but I'm having trouble getting the syntax right. I'm trying to get a count of how many pixels in a bitmap are either red, white, or black, the values for which I have in an enum elsewhere.

In serial processing I have the following code, which works fine:

```
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"Input.png");
        var colourCount = new int[3];

        for (var x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                switch (image.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb())
                {
                    case (int)colours.red: colourCount[0]++; break;
                    case (int)colours.white: colourCount[1]++; break;
                    case (int)colours.black: colourCount[2]++; break;
                    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Unexpected colour found: '{0}'", image.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()));
                }
            }
        }
```

I've seen code for parallel for loops by Microsoft and from Stackoverflow that update a shared variable such as below:

```
        Parallel.For<int>(0, result.Count, () => 0, (i, loop, subtotal) =>
        {
            subtotal += result[i];
            return subtotal;
        },
            (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref sum, x)
        );
```

But all the examples use a simple type such as an int as the shared variable and I just can't figure out the syntax to write to my size three array. Am I approaching this all wrong?

By the way, I know in terms of performance that GetPixel is very slow compared to something like Bitmap.LockBits, I'm just trying to get the principle of parallel loops right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an overload of [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299.aspx) that permits you to maintain thread-local state. In this case, we create an `int[3]` array for each thread that is spawned. Within each iteration of the parallel loop, we only update the *local* array, `localColourCount`. Finally, when the thread is to be retired, we aggregate the results of each local array into the global one, `colourCount`; however, since this is a shared data structure, we enforce mutual exclusion whilst accessing it.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"Input.png");
var colourCount = new int[3];

Parallel.For(0, image.Width,

    // localInit: The function delegate that returns the initial state
    //            of the local data for each task.
    () => new int[3],

    // body: The delegate that is invoked once per iteration.
    (int x, ParallelLoopState state, int[] localColourCount) =>
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
        {
            switch (image.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb())
            {
                case (int)colours.red: localColourCount[0]++; break;
                case (int)colours.white: localColourCount[1]++; break;
                case (int)colours.black: localColourCount[2]++; break;
                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                             string.Format("Unexpected colour found: '{0}'", 
                             image.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()));
            }
        }
    },

    // localFinally: The delegate that performs a final action
    //               on the local state of each task.
    (int[] localColourCount) =>
    {
        // Accessing shared variable; synchronize access.
        lock (colourCount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                colourCount[i] += localColourCount[i];
        }
    });
```

This code assumes that `Bitmap.GetPixel` is thread-safe, which may or may not be the case.

Another thing you need to watch out for is that any `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instances will get combined into an `AggregateException`, so you'll need to adjust your error-handling code.

Comment: You actually don't need `lock` in your `localFinally`. You could instead use `Interlocked.Add()` in your loop. Though using `lock` makes it more obviously correct.

Comment: @svick: Multiple invocations of `Interlocked.Add` might be less efficient than a single `lock`. (Would definitely be the case if the `colourCount` consisted of tens of elements; not sure for 3.) Per [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx): "All of `Interlocked`’s methods generate a full fence." The repeated cache invalidation overhead might exceed the cost of the single lock.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, it makes a lot more sense to me now. You're correct in suggesting that GetPixel isn't thread-safe, in fact accessing any of the images properties or methods seems to be a no-no, so I'll have to figure out a way round that, but I've got the loop itself working fine. Thanks again!